# Sibling Components passing values in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I won't show any code because my question is general. Let's assume I've 3 components in my program named *X,Y,Z.* Now *X* holds a list of *Y*'s and a list of *Z*'s. Moreover, Each *Z* must hold one *Y* out of the list of *Y's* that is under their common *X*. Now I give the user an option to add/edit/delete *X,Y,Z* as much as he wants, but he cannot delete a *Y* if there's a *Z* that has holds him. So what you have to do is first delete the *Z* that holds this *Y* and then you can delete *Y*. My problem is that I do not how I can inform *Y* that the *Z* that held him is deleted. Right now, it only works if I refresh the page, because once I refresh the page *Y* get his parent *X* on ngInit, but otherwise it doesn't get updated. The parent component HTML calls to both components HTML.

I have not attached code because my question is general on the connection between sibling components. If a code is necessary (I think the problem is well detailed) I will attach.

Comment: You can achieve this communication with input/output. Did you try that path?

Comment: @RazRonen I have totally forgot about output, that helped, thanks!

Comment: is there a way that u can draw it and give a data sample ? thanks